# Limits on JSON returned by WCF data services (or IIS 7.5?)

Tags: json, wcf, iis-7.5

I have a WCF data service hosted in IIS 7.5. The method returns JSON.

```
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    CatalogResults SearchBoxADO(string requestBox);
```

(Catalog Results has a count field and then a array of records, each record has 17 fields).

When I get over 3500 records (or at least between 3500 and 4000) the service blows up (no data returned) (I wish I knew what the error is, but our silly firewall (BlueCoat whitelist service) kicks in and blocks me from seeing the result in Fiddler, I know that sounds bizzare, but that is what is happening).

Anyway, I do know that I have to go to a paged response, but I wanted to know what limits there are for WCF JSON (Or is this an IIS limitation) that says that over 2 million bytes in an HTTP response is too much (

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 2081615 Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Date: Mon, 26 Mar
>   2012 16:47:05 GMT
>
> {"count":3500,"results":[{"bbox":"42.73043480000000,-70.77563450000000,42.74424550000000,-70.75736040000000","classification":"U","classificationVal":3,
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

The limit your are reaching might just because of how you configured, or didn't configure your WCF service. To figure out what's the problem you can set up tracing on your service.

[Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Configuration from the link above

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="CardSpace">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IO.Log">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IdentityModel">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```